# Max height and time

Tags: homework-and-exercises, kinematics, projectile

Wes stands on the roof of a building, leans over the edge, and drops a rock. Lindsay waits 1.20 s after Wes releases his rock and throws her own rock straight down at 21.0 m/s. Both rocks hit the ground simultaneously.

1)
Calculate the common height from which the rocks were released. Ignore the effects of air resistance.

Comment: Do you know the equation of motion for a falling object? You should be able to write two equations, with $t$ (time) and $h$ (initial height) as the two unknowns. Then eliminate $t$ with simple rearranging, and you get an equation for $h$ which you can solve. You should be able to try that - if you get stuck, come back and ask for help.

Comment: Hi Cassie, first the bad news, your question  will closed, no research and no attempt, sorry,  but the good news is if you look at this site http://www.physicsclassroom.com/Physics-Tutorial/1-D-Kinematics and read through it, it might help. Or read this , scroll down to uniform motion. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Equations_of_motion

Answer (score 1):

You better show your work first.

Assume the height as $s$ and time taken from the beginning is $t$

For Wes; $s=(1/2)gt^2$

For Lindsay; $s= 21 (t-1.2)+ (1/2)g (t-1.2)^2$

Solve for $s$ now.